# Run IOS error "failed to read asset tags" xcode 10.13

Tags: ios, build

Currently I open a project for IOS, but in the process of opening the project, there is an error.

I hope someone will help. Thank you . . . !

This is an image of the error when running:

[image: Error Screenshot]

Comment: Edit your question to include the error message text, not a screenshot. Also, provide more information: did it ever work, what did you change, etc.

Comment: In my case, closing and reopening my workspace in XCode resolved the issue.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a similar issue that occurred in Xcode 9. Try to remove the reference of Images.xcassets and adding it again.

You can do this by going to the file and deleting it. Then you will be prompted to either delete it or remove the reference.

Comment: Try to redo it, and then delete derived data... With Xcode you never know.

Comment: Could you specify what exactly changes when removing `Assets.xcassets` and added again? Because if the repository remains the same it won't be fixed for other computers.

Answer (score 5):

Set Xcode / File / Workspace Settings / Build system / select "Legacy Build System" and this error went away.

Answer (score 4):

I had this on a CI build of Mac OS where I hadn't opened Xcode before.

After opening XCode I received the pictured prompt stating:
"Install additional required components?"

After clicking install and running the build again the error went away.

On to the next one :P

[image: Xcode prompt requesting to install additional components]

Comment: Thank you for this, setting up a Mac CI is such a high-maintenance task, one random issue after the next.

Answer (score 1):

I got a similar error in a Cordova project.  I had to:

```
cordova platform remove ios
cordova platform add ios
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case Contents.json in the project was interrupted.
When I pressed to the assets menu element Xcode said where the problem exists.

Comment: That helped me. The json was corrupted after git merge. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Note: this fix will only work if Image.Assets are in Git-LFS

Was facing the same issue, I have my Image.assets in Git-LFS so below commands help me to reset my image assets

```
git lfs uninstall
git reset --hard //this will reset you code changes if you have any then you can skip it 
git lfs install
git lfs pull
```